vs code wont run with multiple cpp files
hello i am a beginner and currently following learncpp 2.8 on how to use multiple code files which i was able to build and run manually  but build and fail to run in vs code despite setting tasks.json correctly and having both in the same folder, i am on linux mint gcc11
lerning.cpp (main)
#include<iostream>



int getinteger();
int main()
{
    int x{ getinteger() };
    int y{ getinteger() };

    std::cout << x << " + " << y << " is " << x + y << '\n';
    return 0;
}

getinteger.cpp
#include <iostream>

int getinteger()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}


tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build lerning and getinteger",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-ggdb",
                "-pedantic-errors",
                "-Wall",
                "-Weffc++",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wconversion",
                "-Wsign-conversion",
                "-Werror",
                "lerning.cpp",
                "getinteger.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lerning"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task to build lerning and getinteger"
        }
    ]
}
)

Code-runner: Executor Map
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        


        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "zig": "zig run",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa  ${fileDirname}/**.cpp-o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "scriptcs",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runghc",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "sml": "cd $dir && sml $fileName",
        "mojo": "mojo run",
        "erlang": "escript",
        "spwn": "spwn build",
        "pkl": "cd $dir && pkl eval -f yaml $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.yaml",
        "gleam": "gleam run -m $fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}


tried configuring  to run all cpp files but failed
build log
"Executing task: Build lerning and getinteger
Build lerning and gebinteger+x
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color-always-g-ggdb -pedantic-errors -Wall -Weffc++ -wextra -Wconversion-wsign-conversion -Werror lerning.cpp getinteger.cpp-o /home/mascarad/Desktop/my projects/c++ project/lerning/lerning!
Build finished successfully.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it."
[error](https://i.sstatic.net/lQbQldQ9.png
i tried using "${fileDirname}/**.cpp" and"${fileDirname}\*.cpp"  and just "lerning.cpp","get integer.cpp" and multiple other solutions on posts like this but a lot of them stray of the point like telling me compile manually

How do you run the task? Can you show the logs from it running? My crystal ball says you're not using the task, and instead using the infamous "code runner" extension.

Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output, including the commands used to build.

i do save tasks.json then click control +shift +b to build

Don't post images of text. Copy-paste text as text.

i jut edit as text: Executing task: Build lerning and getinteger
Build lerning and gebinteger+x
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color-always-g-ggdb -pedantic-errors -Wall -Weffc++ -wextra -Wconversion-wsign-conversion -Werror lerning.cpp getinteger.cpp-o /home/mascarad/Desktop/my projects/c++ project/lerning/lerning!
Build finished successfully.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

With that said, it looks like you use the default code-runner plugin and not the command defined in the tasks.json file. Have you installed the Microsoft C and C++ plugin properly? Have you followed the steps outlined in the documentation?

yes i did install c++ plugin then code runner

Remove the code-runner plugin. It's bad and clashes with the MS plugin.

Have you read https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner If you want to use code runner, you have to configure it instead of or in addition to tasks.json.

Build finished successfully. means there's no error. After pressing Ctrl+Shift+B to build, are you trying to run the resulting executable by clicking the "code runner"'s button, perhaps?

yes i read and didnt understand

yes is that worng

In section "Configuration" you can see an example for code-runner.executorMap. In the line "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt" you can see how to configure your build. You could add an entry for the key cpp. But if you didn't understand the documentation, it's probably better to uninstall code runner.

i did try to configure it and it still gave the same error

You did what? Can you edit your question and provide all necessary details?

"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt", You have to configure all source files. $fileName is only one file. You have a working configuration in tasks.json with additional compiler arguments that you could copy. If you don't understand all of this, I recommend compiling from command line and learn each of this command line arguments until you know what this line means. That's the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-14.1.0/gcc/ Here is a summary with most flags: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-14.1.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html

that what i get when not using code runner "Enter an integer: 2
Enter an integer: 0
2 + 0 is 2
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-sua0auvg.t2q" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-euhizzxl.sh1""

Why do you want to use code runner? It works without it. I would even recommend a different editor/IDE. VSCode is not beginner-friendly.

because using g++ seems to complicated at this point

Not g++ is the problem. VSCode with its JSON configurations is the problem. It's almost impossible to configure VSCode if you can't build your project from command line. I recommend Eclipse CDT, Qt Creator, CLion or Visual Studio. Most of them work out of the box. You build and run your project with one button click and without configuration. They use g++ under the hood.

it quite similar but none of the answers on that post worked for me

how can i get vs on linux

AFAIK, you can't. You have to choose a different IDE for Linux.

"it quite similar but none of the answers on that post worked for me" That's not true. The accepted answer works. You insist on using code runner. That's your problem. You are able to build the project without code runner.

thank you all for the answers i started using code::block and it is working perfectly
